# Dynamics GP MuleSoft Connector CreateGLTransactions

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, mulesoft, dynamics-gp

Anybody had success with connecting to Microsoft Dynamics GP through MuleSoft Dynamics GP Connector and creating Transactions using Kerberos Authentication?

Comment: I know that people made it work. That probably is not going to be helpful to you. You may want to improve your question and make it more specific.

Comment: It doesn't work beyond 2015 R2 and that too only in mule 3.x .

Comment: The WSDL in GP connector is outdated. although it captures the outline, it doesn't capture the intricacies, unless someone update the java code underneath.

Comment: And analytical entities are a no go zone for the connector.

Comment: The Mule  4 Dynamics GP connector only supports until 2015 R2 too: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/microsoft-dynamics-gp-connector-release-notes-mule-4